# Doctrine with two Entitymanagers looks at wrong database

Tags: doctrine

I did follow [these rules](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) of setting up a second connection and a second entity manager in doctrine. The "default" database is called `revee` and the  "source" database `reveesrc`.

#### What works

When I dry-run a migration with this code in the `postUp()` method:

```
    /** @var EntityManager $em */
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

    /** @var EntityManager $emSrc */
    $emSrc = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.source_entity_manager');

    var_dump($emSrc->getConnection()->getDatabase());

    $dates = $emSrc->getRepository('App:Dates')->findAll();
```

Weirdly, I get the database `reveesrc` written our **correctly**! Meaning that the mapping from the connection to the entity manager works just fine.

#### What doesn't work

However, the next line produces the error.

```
 Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'revee.dates' doesn't exist"
```

As `dates` was defined in the Entity folder attached to the second source entity manager I thought doctrine would know where to look for the table. What do I have to do to map the Entity to the other source database?

### doctrine.yaml

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:

    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

            source:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL_SOURCE)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                auto_mapping: true
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            source:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: source
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/EntitySrc'
                        prefix: 'App\EntitySrc'
                        alias: App
```

### src\Entity\Dates.php (first lines)

```
<?php

namespace App\EntitySrc;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DateSrcRepository")
 */
class Dates
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
```

### src\Repository\DateSrcRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\EntitySrc\Dates;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class DateSrcRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Dates::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody experiences the same problem, I fixed it by specifying the table explicetly in the entity, prefixing it with the database. If anyone knows if that is not the correct way of solving it I would be interested.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Src;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DateSrcRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="reveesrc.dates")
 */
class Dates
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of entity managers, make sure the default is on the bottem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).